# How to make the following method generic?

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently studying for Object-Oriented Programming and I'm currently studying the chapter Generics. I have the following code from a Java class and what I'm asked to do is to make the last method **calculateSquares** generic. I am really puzzled by it, I can tell you that.

**Here is the class :**

```
public class OefeningWildcards {

public static void main(String[] args){
    new OefeningWildcards().run();
}

public OefeningWildcards(){

}

public void run(){
    Number[] numbers = {2, 3.1, 5, 12, 2.3};
    List<Number> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Number n : numbers){
        numbersList.add(n);


    List<Number> dest = new ArrayList<>();
    calculateSquares(dest, numbersList);

    Double[] doubles = {3.2, 5.6, 4.4, 6.5, 12.2};
    List<Double> doublesList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Number> dest2 = new ArrayList<>();
    calculateSquares(dest2, doublesList);

    List<Double> dest3 = new ArrayList<>();
    calculateSquares(dest3, doublesList);

    }
}


//This method needs to become generic
public void calculateSquares(List<Number> dest, List<Number> src){
    dest.clear();
    for (Number n : src) {
        dest.add(n * n.intValue());
        dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

What I found out is that **List Number** needs to become **List ? extends Number**, like this :

```
public void calculateSquares(List<? extends Number> dest, List<? extends Number> src){
    dest.clear();
    for (Number n : src) {
        dest.add(n * n.intValue());
        dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Thing is, I don't know what to do with the for-loop :

```
for (Number n : src) {
        dest.add(n * n.intValue());
        dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

My logical guess would have been :

```
for (? extends Number n : src) {
        dest.add(n * n.intValue());
        dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

But that seems to be incorrect. What should I do to the for-loop?

Comment: At line 3 : **dest.add(n * n.intValue());** is a "bad operand types for binary operator '*'" error. At line 4 : **dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());** I get a "No suitable method for add(double)" error.

Comment: In the case of the second compiler error, you can't add to a `List<? extends T>` because you don't know what `? extends T` is. Say `T` is `Number`: `? extends Number` might be `Number`, it might be `Integer`, or it might be some class you've just made up which implements `Number`. You can, however, add to `List<? super T>`. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: In the case of the first compiler error, that's because `*` only applies to primitive types, or types which can be auto-unboxed. `Number` can't be. You'd need to call, say, `n.intValue() * n.intValue()` or `n.doubleValue() * n.intValue()`.

Comment: Don't write "solved" into your question title. Accepting the correct answer (the one which answered your question) is all you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually ask for is not possible. At least you can't change the destination list to `? extends Number`. Because then you don't know which type the list is. If it is a `List<Integer>` you can't add a `Double` value there. However what you can do is make the source generic.

The way to go is to add the generic type to the method declaration

```
public void <T extends Number> calculateSquares(List<Number> dest, List<T> src){
    dest.clear();
    for (T n : src) {
        dest.add(n * n.intValue());
        dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

actually once you leave the destination you also can leave your old Method. It still works:

```
public void calculateSquares(List<Number> dest, List<? extends Number> src){
    dest.clear();
    for (Number n : src) {
        dest.add(n * n.intValue());
        dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

as it seems you want add a `List<Double>` or a `List<Number>` to destination. This is possible again by altering the first List and use the super-operator:

```
public void calculateSquares(List<? super Double> dest, List<? extends Number> src){
    dest.clear();
    for (Number n : src) {
        dest.add((double)n * n.intValue());
        dest.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to pass the dest List. Altering values of parameters is not a good practice. We can probably change the return type to List, create a new List ourselves and return it.

Second,  means that you can pass any list that extends number but you **can't** add anything into it. If you want to add then you need to change it to . Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) SO answer for in depth explanation.

Third, we don't need to add the square twice. Adding just once should do. Refer to below example:

```
public List<Number> calculateSquares(List<? extends Number> src){
        List<Number> squares = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Number n : src) {
            squares.add(n.doubleValue() * n.doubleValue());
        }
        return squares;
    }
```